# Dovecot not using my mail_location

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta, thunderbird, dovecot

Using ubuntu 14.04, dovecot, postfix and thunderbird

I'm using dovecot and postfix and have setup the postfix to use Maildir.
I've set in Dovecot

```
mail_location = maildir:/home/%u/Maildir
```

for my mail location in dovecot.conf. But when I try to open my inbox in thunderbird i get this error in the mail.log

```
Error: open(/var/mail/mailuser1) failed: Permission denied (euid=3000(mailuser1) egid=3000(gruppe1) 
missing +w perm: /var/mail, we're not in group 8(mail), dir owned by 0:8 mode=0775)
```

Why is it trying to open var/mail/mailuser1 when i specified the config that the inbox is in /home/%u/Maildir? And how do I fix it? The user should not be in the mail group, but in gruppe1, so I cant move the user to that group.

Comment: Please post your `doveconf -n` output to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Had to put the location in the /dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf or something, then it worked. I guess something overrided my dovecot.conf file..